# Magento custom column in grid doesn't show shipping method chosen in the Order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, shipping, order-grid, column

I have installed Magento CE 1.9.2.4 in one of my sites in Local system.

Now I have overrided `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class into `local` codepool for adding custom columns of `payment_method` and `shipping_method` to it as below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->join(array('sfo' => 'sales/order'),'main_table.entity_id = sfo.entity_id','shipping_method');
        $collection->join(array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id = parent_id','method');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));
        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = array();
        foreach($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
        }
        $this->addColumn('method', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
            'index' => 'method',
            'filter_index' => 'sfop.method',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => $methods,
        ));

        $shMethods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getUsableShippingMethods();
        $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
            'index' => 'shipping_method',
            'filter_index' => 'shipping_method',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => $shMethods
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));
        return $this;
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to understand, if I get the chosen payment `method` correctly displayed into the grid for respective order row, then why I cannot get the chosen `shipping_method` in the same way ?

Any suggestions/flaws into above code or magento collection `join` for `shipping_method` ?

Comment: It's a bad habit to override core files in that way. You can easily add a column using an observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
            $this->setUseAjax(true);
            $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
            $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        }
        /**
         * Retrieve collection class
         *
         * @return string
         */
        protected function _getCollectionClass()
        {
            return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
        }
        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());       
            $collection->join(array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id = parent_id','method'); 
            //Edit Starts:
            $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_method' =>'shipping_method'));
            //Edit Ends:
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
            $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'index' => 'increment_id',
            ));
            if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
                $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                    'index'     => 'store_id',
                    'type'      => 'store',
                    'store_view'=> true,
                    'display_deleted' => true,
                ));
            }
            $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
                'index' => 'created_at',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'width' => '100px',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
                'index' => 'billing_name',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
                'index' => 'shipping_name',
            ));

            $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
            $methods = array();
            foreach($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
                $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
            }
            $this->addColumn('method', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
                'index' => 'method',
                'filter_index' => 'sfop.method',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'width' => '70px',
                'options' => $methods,
            ));
            //Edit Starts:
            $methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
            $shippingmethods = array();
            foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier) {
                if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())  {
                    if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                        $_title = $_ccode;
                    foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)   {
                        $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                        $shippingmethods[$_code]= $_title;
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'index' => 'shipping_method',
            'options' => $shippingmethods,
            ));
            //Edit ends.......
            $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
                'index' => 'base_grand_total',
                'type'  => 'currency',
                'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
                'index' => 'grand_total',
                'type'  => 'currency',
                'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
            ));
            $this->addColumn('status', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'width' => '70px',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
            ));
            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
                $this->addColumn('action',
                    array(
                        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                        'width'     => '50px',
                        'type'      => 'action',
                        'getter'     => 'getId',
                        'actions'   => array(
                            array(
                                'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                                'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                                'field'   => 'order_id',
                                'data-column' => 'action',
                            )
                        ),
                        'filter'    => false,
                        'sortable'  => false,
                        'index'     => 'stores',
                        'is_system' => true,
                ));
            }
            $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));
            return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }
        protected function _prepareMassaction()
        {
            $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
                $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                     'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
                ));
            }
            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
                $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                     'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
                ));
            }
            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
                $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                     'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
                ));
            }
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
            ));
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
            ));
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
            ));
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
            ));
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
            ));
            return $this;
        }
        public function getRowUrl($row)
        {
            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
                return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
            }
            return false;
        }
        public function getGridUrl()
        {
            return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It works, but a little explanation as to why my above code wasn't working (as I don't see much difference in both codes especially in joining the tables for getting shipping) would be great, thanks.

Comment: Hi,
There is nothing wrong with your collection query.
While fetching the shipping methods only you did wrong, like  instead of using Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers() you called Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getUsableShippingMethods();